# Jquery: append element inside tag and before another one

Tags: jquery, html

Let's say I have this HTML

```
<div id="cpu-temperature">
    <p><span class="degrees"> °C</span></p>
</div>
```

I would insert via Jquery the degree **inside** the P and **before** the span.

Of sure, I could (as now) write the span via jquery, but I would elaborate from the script only the "raw" number and not the html.

In fact current code is:

```
$('div#cpu-temperature p').html(cpu_temperature+'<span class="degrees"> °C</span>');
```

Of course I need to beware also for the problem of "append". The temperature logged every 5 second, so a simple "append" flush the page after some time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .prepend() to add to the beginning of whatever element was selected.

```
$('div#cpu-temperature p').prepend(cpu_temperature);
```

Edit -

Since you want to update only the temperature each time, I would add another element before the degrees span. So you have

```
<div id="cpu-temperature">
    <p><span class="temp"></span><span class="degrees"> °C</span></p>
</div>
```

And then just run

```
$('div#cpu-temperature.temp').html(cpu_temperature);
```

I don't know if this is really better than what you were already doing, but I don't think you can just clear the contents of the `<p>` tag without clearing out the child element. At least not easily.

Comment: The script is called every 5 second. With "prepend" the container is full of numbers after some time.... How I can clean them every time?

Comment: So you want to clear and replace the content at the beginning of the <p> tag without removing the rest of it every time the script is called?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, given the posted HTML that you move the `°C` into CSS, using CSS generated content, and then simply updating the text of the element(s), rather than trying to carefully insert it:

```js
$('#cpu-temperature span.degrees').text(function() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 80) + 20;
});
```

```css
span.degrees::after {
  content: '°C';
}
span.degrees:empty::after {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cpu-temperature">
  <p><span class="degrees"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cz82wn8y/).

Answer (score 0):

that'd make it:

```js
 var span = '<span class="degrees"> °C</span>';
 setInterval(function() {
   var degree = Math.round((Math.random() + 1) * 30);
   $('#cpu-temperature p').html(degree + span);
 }, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cpu-temperature">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the HTML of `p tag` into `variable` then every 5 second in your interval we can replace the current HTML with the default so we can `prepend` without any problem.

```js
var defHTML = $('div#cpu-temperature p').html();

setInterval(function(){
  var cpu_temperature = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80) + 20;
  $('div#cpu-temperature p').html(defHTML);
  $('div#cpu-temperature p').prepend(cpu_temperature);
},500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cpu-temperature">
    <p><span class="degrees"> °C</span></p>
</div>
```

**Anther Solution**

You can `prepend` any HTMl element in `<p>` tag, then you can change this element html

```js
$('#cpu-temperature p').prepend('<span class="tempNum"></span');
 setInterval(function() {
   var cpu_temperature = Math.round((Math.random() + 1) * 30);
   $('#cpu-temperature p span.tempNum').html(cpu_temperature);
 }, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cpu-temperature">
    <p><span class="degrees"> °C</span></p>
</div>
```